# Unable to build Angular project after migrating to 6.0

Tags: angular, colors, angular6

I have updated an Angular project from 5.2 to 6.0. I followed the official guide and everything went almost without a problem.
But when I try to build I get a following problem:

```
ERROR in Module build failed:
var colors = require('./colors');
  ^Invalid CSS after "v": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "var colors = requir"
      in /documents/project/node_modules/colors/lib/index.js
```

I understand Angular checks this JS file as it was CSS but I am not really sure about how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Downgrade sass-loader to version 6.0.7 and it should compile.

`npm install sass-loader@6.0.7 --save`

Comment: Seems like an issue with sass-loader indeed ... not using colors.scss anymore and rename the file to variables or anything else seems to solve the issue as well